# Windows Media Player Will Not Play MP4 Over HTTPS

Tags: video-streaming, windows-media-player

I have a site that serves videos. These videos are served over HTTPS as MP4 files. Problem is I can not get Windows Media Player to stream it.

The videos play in the `<video>` tag on a web page in all the browsers. The video plays if I stick the URL into VLC. The video plays if downloaded and then played in Windows Media Player. But if I point Windows Media Player to the URL (say someone clicked a link and Windows automatically opened the player) it just sits there with the message "Connecting...".

I can not find any logs or other means of figuring out why Windows Media Player does not like streaming my video. Where should I look? What should I check?

Comment: I moved the moov atom to the start of the file.

Comment: How did you fix this?